# Torrential +downpour?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

At this very moment, I am adding the word **''torrential''**(adjective) in my vocabulary list(*also it sounds awesome and smart to say this-just from a non-native perspective hehe*)however, **Goggle** exemplifies its usage in a sentence that says:

> ''[a torrential downpour](https://www.google.com/search?ei=vYLYWszYCcGm0gTerIr4CA&q=torrential&oq=torrential&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.0.35i39i70i249j0i67l2j0l2.1419548.1421161..1422879...2....681.3026.0j2j6j5-2..........1..mobile-gws-wiz-serp.....3..35i39j0i131j0i131i67.17Alw67GbdY%3D)''

Come to think of it:

- torrential=a rapid and copius in quantity(also heavy)
- [downpour](https://www.google.com/search?ei=TojYWo_ECsyv0gSlz6DgBg&q=downpour%20meaning&oq=downpour&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.1.1.0i67j0l4.15294.19377..20410...1....414.2996.0j2j8j0j2..........1..mobile-gws-wiz-serp.....3..0i71j0i10j35i39j0i131.u6nXxaqu9Zg%3D)=a heavy rain

**''A torrential downpour''** will mean **''a heavy heavy rain''** am I right that it now becomes redundant/incorrect?

Comment: It's not that uncommon to double up an extreme adjective with an extreme noun to express **really** extreme conditions.  A "catastrophic disaster"; a feeling of "blissful ecstasy"; a "torrential downpour."

Comment: Nice this clarifies my question, thx very much man

Answer (score 1):

Using those definitions it does sound redundant, but it adds colour to the phrase.

> It was a downpour

sounds bad

> It was a torrential downpour

Makes me think of rain where you are soaked to the skin through your waterproof coat before you make the garden gate.